# How to include a file in a Jupyter Notebook on startup

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is there a simple way to allow a user to set a flag to include a file when starting a Jupyter notebook instance? I'm deploying notebook instances through a Kubernetes client and wanting to have the ability to optionally include a file that is visible once the instance starts up. Is this something I can configure through the jupyter_config file?